# Dask distributed: How to computationally recognize if worker is idling?

Tags: python, dask, distributed, dask-distributed

I'd like to monitor dask workers and restart them when they are stuck in idle.
Is there a way to detect idling workers, e.g. by computing the average CPU utilization of the worker in the last minute?

Comment: Have you tried the dashboard? it shows CPU utilisation graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look at the scheduler state in `Scheduler.workers`

Try

```
workers = client.run(lambda dask_scheduler: dask_scheduler.workers)
```

Then look at the `.metrics` attribute of each `WorkerState` object

```
{address: ws.metrics["cpu"] for address, ws in workers.items()}
```

(Here I pulled out CPU, but there is a lot of information in there)

You might also want to look at Adaptive scheduling